# Merge data from NetCDF files

Tags: netcdf, netcdf4, nco, ncdf4

I am new to NetCDF files. I have daily data on global sea surface temperature from 1981-2014 from NOOA's [AVHRR Pathfinder data version 5.3](https://data.nodc.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/iso?id=gov.noaa.nodc:AVHRR_Pathfinder-NCEI-L3C-v5.3). The [dataset](https://data.nodc.noaa.gov/pathfinder/Version5.3/L3C/) consists of 365x2 .nc files for each year: one each for night and day temperatures for each day in a given year.

I wish to merge the various daily .nc files of each year into one annual .nc file for each year. What is the most efficient way of doing this? I have explored the `nco` package using Anaconda but I'm [running into problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49522859/error-importing-importing-the-nco-class-in-python). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend program "cdo" and more precisely operator "mergetime".
For example:
cdo mergetime ncfile1 ncfile2 outputfile